# How to solve an equation with powers in it: $16y+4y^2=-11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Hello I'm confused as to how I simplify this equation or if it's even possible.
$$16y+4y^2=-11$$
I was trying to get the logarithm of everything so I could get the exponent as a factor but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I was trying to get the logarithm of everything so I could get the exponent as a factor but it didn't seem to work

Comment: I mean the ln of each term

Comment: Have you ever heard the words "quadratic equation" or "quadratic formula"?

Comment: Oh yeah. God I'm dumb. So I could make it $16y+4y^2+11=0$ and then use the quadratic formula or just try and factories:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case of a second-order equation, for $y \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$ay^2+by+c=0$$
$$\Delta=b^2-4ac; \Delta \geq 0$$ 
$$y_{±}=\dfrac{-b±\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to
$$
4y^2 + 16y + 11 = 0
$$
Now this is a quadratic equation.